# Google Maps API warning: SignedInDeprecated

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use [Google Maps JavaScript API V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).
Since some days, I get this error in the console :

> Google Maps API warning: SignedInDeprecated https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#signed-in-deprecated

But I can't get any informations about this error on SO or with the link provided.

Does anyone have an explanation?

**UPDATE : For some reason, this error doesn't appear in the French version, hence my question.**

Comment: Will be removed in future versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#signed-in-deprecated) says:

> **SignedInDeprecated**    Warning
>
> The signed_in parameter is deprecated and will be ignored in future versions of the Google Maps JavaScript API. It won't prevent the Google Maps JavaScript API from working after signed-in mode has retired, but the behavior of your application may change, if you rely on current signed-in features.
>
> Please review your application and see Signed-in Maps | Google Maps JavaScript API for details about the upcoming changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my version, I don't see that !

Comment: Is it a different language version?  Those are sometimes behind the english version. Maybe a refresh might help.

Comment: Indeed, It is hidden for french translation. Don't understand why. Great, I will correct that.

Answer (score 1):

As [geocodezip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40249537/3452348) explains, `Signed-in Maps` will be deprecated from 3.27 version of Google maps JavaScript API.

For an unknow reason, this parameter isn't visible in French translation (at the moment of writing this answer).

**Solution :**

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/signedin), to remove this warning in the console, simply remove the parameter `signed_in=true` like this :

```
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=YOUR_API_KEY" async defer>
</script>
```